# Force Jekyll to re-read files in a collection to _site after a Hook runs

Tags: ruby, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I've written a Hook for my Jekyll site that takes a `.json` file from my `_data` directory, creates a bunch of `.md` files from it's content and stores them in a `_collection`.

The problem is by the time Jekyll executes this Hook it's done reading the `_collection` and so the *new or updated* files don't make it into `_site`.

---

**So:** I'm thinking I need a way to make Jekyll re-read the `_collection` after the Hook runs. Thus updating the necessary files in `_site` before render.

---

#### Here's my Hook

```
jekyll::Hooks.register :site, :post_read do |site|
  if site.data.has_key? 'projects'
    site.data['projects'].each do |project|
      File.open("./_projects/#{file_name}.md") do |file|
        # A bunch of YAML Front-Matter written to file.
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I believe `:post_read` is about as early as the Hook can run. Any earlier and `site.data` is empty.

I've already tried a `Generator` but the same problem occurred as *["Generators run after Jekyll has made an inventory of the existing content"](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#generators)*.

I know I could have the files output directly into `_site` but there are a few reasons I don't want to do that.

1. By outputting the files as `.md` with `YAML` Front-Matter to a `_collection` I can let Jekyll do the conversion and rendering to html. This seems practical, as that's what Jekyll is for.
2. `_site` is always dumped, so by storing these files in a `_collection` they'll stick around. Just incase the `.json` file is't there or what ever.

   - Plus, eventually there will be some conditionals added to the Hook so only what needs *updating* or *creating* will be processed through the Hook. But I'd still want the existing files to be rendered to `_site`.

---

**Also** Just incase it's relevant:

- The `.json` file will be automatically updated from a Google Spreadsheet whenever it *(the Spreadsheet)* changes. And then whenever the `.json` file changes Jekyll will need to update the site *(thus running the Hook)*.
- I'm currently developing locally, but the site will eventually be served up as a ***Gitlab Page***.
- This is my first time working with Jekyll, and I only started learning Ruby about a week ago. So please explain like I'm a total noob *(as I am)*.

---

---

## Update

Although I'm sure Jekyll will have a method for this, I have implemented a workaround for now.

```
projects = File.read('./_data/projects.json')
projects_file = JSON.parse(projects)
projects_file.each do |project|
  File.open("./_projects/#{file_name}.md", 'w+') do |file|
    # A bunch of YAML Front-Matter written to file.
  end
end
```

- This script executes before Jekyll's :after_init event

Answer (score 0):

--- The following is only an idea and is untested. ---

How about initializing a new `Jekyll::Collection` instance after all the "project" `documents` have been written to?

```
Jekyll::Hooks.register :site, :post_read do |site|
  if site.data.has_key? 'projects'
    site.data['projects'].each do |project|
      File.open("./_projects/#{file_name}.md") do |file|
        # A bunch of YAML Front-Matter written to file.
      end
    end

    # Re-read collections in this site
    Jekyll::CollectionReader.new(site).read
  end
end
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I wouldn't say I know for sure why, but I believe it's because by the time the Hook runs Jekyll has finished reading `site`.

Comment: I see.. I read your question again. It looks like you already have the collection `projects` configured in your config file and read into `Jekyll::Site.collections`. So, I think, re-reading the entire `Collection` dataset with `CollectionReader.new(site).read` should help. I'll update my answer to illustrate.

Comment: That's just returning `Error:  uninitialized constant CollectionReader`. It sounds like it could be what I'm after though. Do you know any resources I can checkout to learn more about `CollectionReader`? I've already tried [rubydoc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/jekyllplusadmin/1.1.0/Jekyll/CollectionReader), but that doesn't do much explaining.

Comment: My bad.. `CollectionReader` is a class under `Jekyll` module. So it should've been `Jekyll::CollectionReader.new()`. Updated answer.

Comment: Regarding the resources for further reading, this is [method called](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/jekyll/3.4.3/Jekyll%2FCollectionReader:read) in my answer and this is the [source](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/v3.4.3/lib/jekyll/readers/collection_reader.rb#L11-L18) for the same.

Comment: `Jekyll::CollectionReader.new()` doesn't return any error. But it doesn't work either. I've edited my question to include a workaround I've implemented for now.

Comment: Ok.. glad you found a way through eventually.